# Kubernetes Ingress + Apache airflow

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-ingress

Can you please help me?

I'm trying to start Apache airflow in Kubernetes (AWS), in vpc.
I'm using helm stable/airflow 7.1.1

Everything starts ok. But to get access to web interface I need to expose it via ingress ELB.
I have this setup.
The rule for airflow looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-proxy-header: upgrade
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    creationTimestamp: "2020-05-29T14:52:54Z"
    generation: 31
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: airflow-dev-web
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Tiller
      app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow-dev-web
      app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0"
      helm.sh/chart: web-service-0.1.0
    name: airflow
    namespace: dev
    resourceVersion: "45272238"
    selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/dev/ingresses/airflow
    uid: 64f276ad-b51f-4551-8078-51a7184b04b4
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: public.host.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: airflow-dev-web
            servicePort: 8080
          path: /airflow(/|$)(.*)
  status:
    loadBalancer:
      ingress:
      - ip: <public_ip>
```

I can open the /health with is OK:

https://public.host.com/airflow/health

But when I open admin web endpoint:

https://public.host.com/airflow/admin

I have many not rewritten urls - they are pointing to public.host.com but not to public.host.com/airflow/ .... Like this:

```
URL: https://public.host.com/admin/admin/bootstrap/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css?v=3.3.5
Status: 404 Not Found
```

I found that I need special setup for reverse proxy.. Like here:

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/run-behind-proxy.html

But I cannot find how to do this using Ingress.... :((

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not actual anymore.
Have won it using:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

Also it will be needed to setup in airflow:

```
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX: "True"
```

and

```
baseUrl: "http://local.airflow/airflow"
```

Comment: your public url path is `public.host.com` then why you set your baseUrl as local.airflow ?

Comment: I've pretty much the same configuration as yours, but I cannot make it work as per your provided answer. Could you have a look please ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054071/how-to-redirect-from-specified-path-in-the-ingress-file-to-the-root-path-of-the