# How to redirect from specified path in the ingress file to the root path of the service

Tags: redirect, airflow, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-config, nginx-ingress

I have an ingress defined as follows;

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webserver-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
     rewrite ^(/master)$ $1/ redirect;
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.test.domain
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /master
        backend:
          serviceName: airflow-webserver-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

The service `airflow-webserver-svc` is pointing towards airflow webserver. the ingress now hits airflow webserver on GET /, but the site gets redirected from my.test.domain/master to my.test.domain/home which is the landing page of airflow webserver, but nginx returns 404 Page not found on that link :(. All works fine if I change the ingress `path: /`, going to my.test.domain open up airflow webserver /home page, which then gets redirected to /login page. But I need to open the same webpage from my.test.domain/master. How can I do that ?

It doesn't redirect from path: "/master" to "/" inside the service. Is
there any way to redirect from specified path in the ingress file to the root path of the service?

**UPDATE:**

Found out that airflow has its special configuration to do, when running behind proxy ([here](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/run-behind-proxy.html)). I applied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103439/5167801) solution but still no luck.

Comment: Could you edit your question with a full Ingress config including the rewrites that you added?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor done. I think m having same problem as https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/646#issuecomment-444343714

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor simplified the question further.

Answer (score 1):

Made it work by keeping ingress same as mentioned above, and adding this in airflow config under webserver section;

```
[webserver]
  enable_proxy_fix = True
  base_url = http://my.test.domain/master/
```

and restart the webserver.